# Angularjs: how to Fadeout div element when sorted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fadeout

I am sorting data based upon timer. Lower the timer higher their position.

Eg:

```
No      Timer      
1.      0h:39m     [+1hr]
2.      01h:22m    [+1hr]
3.      03h:01m    [+1hr]
```

when I press [+1hr], it will increase 1 hour on the selected value and sorts it. But it does not have good UI Effect. Its fast and we dont notice the sort.

To prevent confusion on weather the timer was added or not, I want smooth transition so that the users know that its working.

I want it to Fadeout slowly and may be display short message like:

> "1hr added! Sorting now..."

and then sort.

My current code is:

```
<div ng-repeat="player in AllPlayers | orderBy: 'timer'">
    <div id="SingleCard" class="card">
      HTML / ANGUAR Code
    </div>
</div>
```

When [+1] is clicked, the `id="SingleCard"` should do the trick. It should fadeout when sorting.

How can I do this with Anguarjs or jQuery?

Comment: How you trigger the click? where is the click event?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I have not been able to create that function. But I kept the id="SingleCard" just to give more clarification which div it would work :)